# How to get the arrays in a variable which can be stored as different arrays?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In `$marks` I stored marks obtained by some students in 2 subjects.

When I execute below code:

```
print_r($marks);
```

A combined array is generated and outputs the following:

```
Array ( [Dane] => 1 [Mary] => 6 [Jon] => 2) Array ( [Dane] => 3 [Mary] => 2 [Jon] => 1) Array ( [Dane] => 2 [Mary] => 7 [Jon] => 1)
```

How do I store the marks of students in each subject in separate variable?

```
Array ( [Dane] => 1 [Mary] => 6 [Jon] => 2) 
is marks in subject 1

Array ( [Dane] => 2 [Mary] => 7 [Jon] => 1)
is marks in subject 2.
```

I also want to do so for n number of subjects if there are n subjects.

Comment: try $marks[$i];

Comment: Right. But how can you tell what student belong to what subjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your subjects are already separated!

```
$subject1 = $marks[1];
$subject2 = $marks[2];
```

if you have n subjects and you insist to separate them, do this :

```
for($i=0; $i<n; $i++){
    ${"subject$i"} = $marks[$i]
}
```

then you have separated variables :

$subject1,$subject2, . . .

Comment: I tried this and solved the problem. for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
$c=$i+1;
${"subject".$c}=$this->input->post('marks_'.$c);
}